# What software is used to produce this video?

Tags: video

Any suggestions for the software used to make this video?

http://vimeo.com/65571323

The drawings can be made in illustrator, but I can't figure out how to animate it.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly looks hand animated to me, however the digital equivalent would be to start with vector graphics and animate them in something like Flash or After Effects.  Either product is capable of keyframe animation of various assets including vector graphics.

Personally, I'd rank them by likelihood as by hand and scanned, followed by Flash, followed by After Effects as the possibilities.  Keyframe animation allows for objects to be set at a start point and an end point and the computer fills in the values in-between.

Answer (score 0):

His vimeo tags seem to point to it being made in Flash. You could produce similar in most animating software though, such as After Effects, once you've created your drawings.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that while After Effects can be used to do some particular basic animations, it is not an animation software, it is a compositing software designed for layering and effects work.  Animation software, such as Flash, is a different class of tool entirely.